# DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged not triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my problem, I've a `dropdownlist` in my asp.net and a `gridview`. Based on DropDownList's selected value, I would like to change the content/bind data to GridView. But it's not happening, `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event not firing on change.

Aspx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpRegion" runat="server" CssClass="ddlfield" AutoPostBack="true"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpRegion_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Aspx.cs code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDropDown();    //data binding for dropdownlist
        BindRegionWiseTally();    //data binding for gridview
    }
}

protected void drpRegion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     BindRegionWiseTally();   //data binding for gridview
}
```

I have set Page's `EnableViewState="false"` based on suggestions.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in the event code to see if it's firing or are you basing this on the grid view not updating?

Comment: You want to remove `EnableViewState="false"`.

Comment: Does it work with enabled ViewState? Have you used the debugger to veryify that the event isn't triggered? Does the page post back at all(check if by setting a breakpoint in `Page_Load`)?

Comment: is it just your `drpRegion_SelectedIndexChanged` that is not triggered, or you can't even get the page to postback when dropdown value is changed?

Comment: @Rohit: I tried with putting break point on change event, but it does not triggered! And the values in dropdown list got cleared!

Comment: So I guess your page load is getting fired and since you're binding your DropDownList only if its not post back the DropDownList values gets cleared. You can check this by having a breakpoint in your pageload event.

Comment: @Rohit yes you r right! DropDownList values got cleared once I try to change the selectedvalue.

Comment: @Win If i try to remove EnableViewState="false", then I'm getting below error on changing dropdownlist. Failed to load viewstate. `The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.`

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo: are you adding controls dynamically somewhere? Then you have to re-create those controls on consecutive postbacks in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`, not later.

Comment: @TimSchmelter no, I am not adding any controls dynamically!

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the BindDropDown() method to earlier in the Page lifecycle and doing it unconditionally.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    BindDropDown();//data binding for dropdownlist
}
```

To clarify - yes, it is because you set the Page's EnableViewState to false.

In fact, it is not only the selected value - the whole list of dropdown items (which is persisted in the ViewState) should have probably disappeared for you.

The SelectedValue property is set once we have the list of items, it depends on it.

With the ViewState disabled, you do not have that list restored automatically on every postback from it.

Comment: tried this, whatever i select on dropdownlist it changed to Index-0(I mean drpRegion.SelectedValue becomes 0)..!

Comment: should i suppose change the EnableViewState to 'true'?

Answer (score 1):

As i don't find any change in code when i tried it the Dropdownchange event is firing,please keep the break point and check it,

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">Tracking Reader</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2" Selected ="True" >Dropbox Reader</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Aspx.cs Code

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDropDown();//data binding for dropdownlist
            //BindRegionWiseTally();//data binding for gridview
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Invoked sucessfully.");
    }
    protected void BindDropDown()
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("All");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("New");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Update");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("Delete");
    }
```

Comment: I tried by putting break point, but it does not fired as expected!

Comment: what do you mean by not fired as expected..?? how you want to fire it..??

Comment: I mean, even putting break point inside change event, control not transferred!

Comment: It's working fine as u said, when we add values to DropDownList on aspx page as u gave above. I'm getting error when am trying add data to DropDownList from DB in codebind.

Comment: what error you are getting can please mention and show me the code how you are trying to bind the data.